# Prove $x/(1+nx^2)$ uniformly converges to zero.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

$f_n(x) = \frac{x}{1+nx^2}$.  Prove $f_n$ converges pointwise over all $\mathbb{R}$ to $f(x) = 0$.  Is this convergence uniform?

My proof is below.

1. Can you verify it?
2. Is there a simpler or more direct approach than taking $1/f_n$?

Proof: Choose $N > 1/\epsilon|x|$.  Then $|\frac{x}{1+nx^2}| < |\frac{x}{nx^2}| = |\frac{1}{nx}| < \epsilon$.

The convergence is uniform.  Choose $N > 1/\epsilon^2$.  For $x=0$, the matter is trivial.  Else, $1/f_n(x) = \frac{1}{x} + nx$.  Assume $x>0$.  If $x \leq 1/\sqrt{n}$, then $1/x \geq \sqrt{n}$, and if $x \geq 1/\sqrt{n}$, then $nx \geq 1/\sqrt{n}$.  Hence, $1/f_n(x) \geq 1/\sqrt{n}$, and $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$.  A similar argument holds for $ x < 0$.

Answer (score 2):

As regards your proof, I did not get the last part: "Hence, $1/f_n(x) \geq 1/\sqrt{n}$, and $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $n > N$."

Another (simpler) way: for any $x\in \mathbb{R},$
$$(1-\sqrt{n}x)^2\geq 0\implies 1+nx^2\geq 2\sqrt{n}x\implies |f_n(x)|\leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}.$$
Then uniform convergence of $(f_n)_n$ over $\mathbb{R}$ follows instantly.

Comment: Marvelous. Can you explain how you realized to go in this direction? For example, how did you know to bound $f_n$ by $1/2\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: @SRobertJames If you take the derivative of $f_n$ then you will easily found where $|f_n(x)|$ attains its maximum value.